# "having" clause to filter students' sate of residence where count of Male > Female

Tags: sql-server, case, having

Please see the following query:

```
select 
    s.state 
from 
    students as s
group by 
    s.state 
having 
    count(case when s.gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) > count(case when s.gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end)
```

This query will run but returns nothing. I'm trying to select & group by state where the count of males is greater than that of females. What is the issue with the query?

Comment: maybe you mean sum rather than count. it will still count a 0

Comment: AHH that's the issue.. ok thank you. Dumb mistake!

Comment: Remove `else 0` or switch to `sum`. I usually favour `count` without `else` but don't think there is any difference.

Comment: You may also have nulls in that column

Comment: Learn to debug SQL. If you add (temporarily) the aggregates into the column list of the select statement, you can at least SEE the numbers that are computed to understand why you logic does or does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I should be using sum, instead of count. Dumb mistake...